# Display value of a column after checking boolean value of another column - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    pd.DataFrame({
    'total_discounted_cost_bef_929': [490, 0, 490, 0],
    'total_discounted_cost_aft_929': [525, 0, 525, 0],
    'aft_929_bool': [False, False, True, True]
})
```

I want to create a new column called 'final_cost'. If 'aft_929_bool' == False, I want the output to be the value in the 'total_discounted_cost_bef_929' column. And the opposite for any True value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `np.where`

```
df['New']=np.where(df['aft_929_bool'],df['total_discounted_cost_aft_929'], df['total_discounted_cost_bef_929'])
df
Out[117]: 
   total_discounted_cost_bef_929  ...  New
0                            490  ...  490
1                              0  ...    0
2                            490  ...  525
3                              0  ...    0
[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I'm always trying to apply lambda functions to these types of problems, but it seems like np.where is the better option when I want to check the value of 2 or more columns?

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr. then check with np.select ~